# How can I use a Mirrorbow USB25IO board with a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, usb, io

I found an IO board in my closet, and I would like to use it with my MacBook pro.

The text on the board is "Mirrorbow Electronics USB IO V1.2"

I found this link to a manual:

http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jason.haywood/Technical/USBIOManualold.pdf

It indicates that the board should emulate a usb serial port adapter, but no serial port appears in /dev/ when the board is attached.

Tailing /var/log/system.log while attaching gives these three lines:

```
0        1 AppleUSBCDCACMData: start - Find CDC driver for ACM data interface failed
0        1 AppleUSBCDCECMData: start - Find CDC driver for ECM data interface failed
AppleUSBCDC: Version number - 4.3.2b1
```

The USB info for the board is:

```
USB IO:

  Product ID:   0x000a
  Vendor ID:    0x04d8  (Microchip Technology Inc.) 
  Version:  0.00   Speed:   Up to 12 Mb/sec
  Manufacturer: Mirrorbow Electronics
  Location ID:  0x14200000 / 6
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    100
```

Using the Ruby gem "libusb", I can attach to the board:

```
require "libusb"
usb = LIBUSB::Context.new
usb.devices(:idVendor => 0x04d8, :idProduct => 0x000a)
=> [#<LIBUSB::Device 20/6 04d8:000a Mirrorbow Electronics USB IO ? (Comm (00,00))>]
```

I would prefer a way to use it with Ruby, but *any* solution is OK.

Any way to access this board from OS X and use the I/O?

Comment: As Macs have never had COM & LPT ports, I'm pretty sure this is not going to work. According to the docs, it was only ever designed to work on Windows. You might have better luck on Boot Camp or in a VM, but I'm guessing you're still going to have to find the drivers from somewhere.